# jquery linear gauge with custom labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a good free/paid linear gauge widget? I'm looking for something like this:
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Gauges/DifferentSubvalueIndicatorTypesLinearGauge/jQuery/Light/

which is great but lacks the option to append custom text to the labels (subvalues)

Comment: You could check out the various options provided by [C3](http://c3js.org/examples.html), a library of pre-packaged charts that sits on top of [D3](https://d3js.org/)...

Comment: no linear gauge and no labels :(